# Free monitoring tool to understand stress on resources of VMS, host etc.?

Tags: gratis, monitoring, virtual-machine

I want to monitor few basic resources (memory, CPU etc.) on my VMS and the host. What is a good free monitoring tool that I can use?

My yardsticks are:

- Easy to setup
- Easy to visualize resources on VMS, hosts

Comment: I looked into few like Nagios, Zabbix, cacti e.t.c but am confused .. zabbix does polling not pushing, nagios seems to need a learning curve ..